# Bing-map display all pins on same location how to prevent overlapping on same location

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, overlapping, pins

I am trying to display all pins which are on same location currently pins are overlapping.
how to create a distance between them?

I also attached my fiddle link.

`code` https://jsfiddle.net/rd8ehjgt/2/

[Overlapping issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIOIp.jpg)